# How to configure a modal window to fit the actual size of the contained image?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4.2, to show a popup window (modal) with an image in real size (100%) in both width and height, as long as the size of the browser window allows, and if not, that is, if the image is larger than the size of the window, then it will be reduced automatically. I have tried with the following code, but the image is enlarged (+ 100%) in the width of the modal, although I configured it with **max-width: 100%**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Imagen 100%</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        .img-100{
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
       }
    </style>
    <a href="#modalArticulo" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Launch modal</a>
    <div id="modalArticulo" class="modal fade " tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <img src="../images/Imagen360x360.jpg" class="img-100">
           <!-- <img src="../images/Imagen1200x1200.jpg" class="img-100"> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The images will be loaded dynamically, so I can not know the size of the images by default.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the margin to auto will prevent the image from stretching to fill the width and height of the modal div. You do not need to set max-width or max-height of the image.

```
.modal-image {
    margin: auto
}
```

Furthermore add this class to make the modal fit to the picture and center on the screen. Without it, the modal will display borders around the image.

```
.modal-content {
     width: unset;
     margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: This did not work well, it is not responsive. Try a larger image than the window, for example 1200x1200.
   
    <a href="#modalArticulo" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Launch modal</a>
    <div id="modalArticulo" class="modal modal-image fade " tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <img src="../images/Imagen360x360.jpg" class="">
           <!-- <img src="../images/Imagen1200x1200.jpg" class=""> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>